# How to obtain httpServletRequest in validate method of SpringWebFlow

Tags: spring-webflow

I need to access httpServletRequest in the validate method of spring webflow. Please help me how to do this.

My webflow for view state is:

```
    <var name="search" class="com.test.form.Search"/>
...................
    <view-state id="search" model="search" view="searchPage"> 
            <transition on="submit" to="searchAction">
            </transition>
        </view-state>
...............
```

validate method in search model class is:

```
public void validateLoanSearch(ValidationContext context) {
//I need to get a httpServletRequest here...
}
```

In action/controller class I can get it thru RequestContext but ValidationContext gives only the messageContext. Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution.

In the bean class or validator class inside the validate method use this:

```
RequestContext rc = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
```

RequestContextHolder is becoming available inside the validate method.